# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS forgets audio output device setting on reboot

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

Audio works fine.  But any time I reboot the audio settings changes to select digital output (S/PDIF) built-in audio even though nothing is plugged in to that jack.  So each time I reboot I have to go in to the settings to point to line out - Built-in-audio.

Not a huge problem but inconvenient.
I did see similar questions and answers but those questions were quite old and not on point.

I haven't done testing to see if other settings are effected since the system is running perfectly otherwise.

Shouldn't the change in audio output settings be remembered automatically?  I see no save button.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To force pulse audio to use the most recently selected output source:

```
sudo vi /etc/pulse/default.pa
```

Comment out this line:

```
load-module module-switch-on-port-available
```

to:

```
#load-module module-switch-on-port-available
```

Save and exit.

Restart pulse audio:

```
pulseaudio -k
```