# Sound volume control not working until device switch

Tags: sound, volume-control

Since some days my volume control is not working. I open the settings and can move the slider and nothing happen.

If I run Youtube on Chrome I can move the specific slider for Chrome and this works.

To fix the problem I must change the output device and after that the control works normal.

I am not very good at Ubuntu so I have no idea which journal or anything like that I have to read to get some more information.

Maybe it is important. My default device was switching after every reboot so I have exploit in this post:
[Ubuntu 22.04 LTS forgets audio output device setting on reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1488615/ubuntu-22-04-lts-forgets-audio-output-device-setting-on-reboot)